# How to add Setting Page in my plugin after updating plugin

Tags: plugins

I had created a plugin, but now I need to add a setting Page. If I remove plugin through `composer remove` and install it again through `composer require`, I get the setting page, but if I just update the plugin files and do an uninstall and install, I do not see the setting page. The reason is first my `composer.json` file has `"hasCpSettings": false` which added the same in `plugin.php` file. But now I have `"hasCpSettings": true`, so I guess just updating the plugin or doing an uninstall/install from plugin setting doesn't update the `plugin.php` file. Is `composer remove` and then `composer require` the only way of getting setting page ? As this would be hard doing on a server with no terminal access.